# How to properly save one hashed password

Tags: python, file, security, hash, passwords

I was trying something when I came across this problem. I have a hashed password stored in a file on my computer. However the way my code detects whether or not a password has already been set is it checks if that file exists. If it does than it will ask you for the password that has been set. If the file does not exist than it will ask you to set a new password. But this also means that theoretically if someone wanted to break in they could just delete that file and enter a new password.

How do you go about solving this? I am not sure if this is a totally stupid question or not but I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: If someone has access to your server to the extent that they can delete passwords you have a bigger problem than they can just log in

Comment: You should have salted password hashes and if the hashed password doesn't exist authorisation should always fail not ask for a new password

Comment: It has been salted

Comment: What hash are you using? You should use `Scrypt` to hash passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Unix or Unix-like system, you can let set the file ownership to root and make it only readable by authorized users, clearing other bits. This should prevent from deleting the file.

```
sudo chown root:root file_with_hashed_password
sudo chmod 440 file_with_hashed_password
```

Comment: To prevent deleting you have to set the permissions for *the folder* the file is in.

Comment: Thank you but I decided that if the file does not exist than you cannot enter. However now I do not know how to track if a password has already been set or not

Comment: Use a default password

Comment: I guess.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to ask for a password at all.
Just deny all other users access to your script by settings permissions.

If you are sharing your user account consider someone could simply remove the password prompt from your script.